# Gitolite macro to expand to user name?

Tags: gitolite

I have a config file with something like:

```
repo qt/[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+
  C      = @admins
  RW+    = @admins
  R      = @users
  RW bob = bob
```

As you can see every user (in group @users) can read all branches
and I want bob to be able to create and push to a branch bob (and also to bob/fix and so on).

Is there a macro that would expand to the users name?
I would like to do something like:

```
repo qt/[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+
  C       = @admins
  RW+     = @admins
  R       = @users
  RW USER = USER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one Gitolite feature which would look close to what you want is "**[personal branch](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/special.html#pers)**"

> "Personal" branches are great for environments where developers need to share work but can't directly pull from each other (usually due to either a networking or authentication related reason, both common in corporate setups).
>
> Personal branches exist in a namespace of their own. The syntax is

```
RW+ personal/USER/  =   @userlist
```

> where the "personal" can be anything you like (but cannot be empty), and the "`/USER/`" part is necessary (including both slashes).
>
> A user "`alice`" (if she's in the userlist) can then push any branches inside `personal/alice/`.
>   Which means she can push `personal/alice/foo` and `personal/alice/bar`, but NOT `personal/alice`.
>
> (Background: at runtime the "`USER`" component will be replaced by the name of the invoking user. Access is determined by the right hand side, as usual).

That means, when you are looking for "Is there a macro that would expand to the users name?", `/USER/` would be an example of a "macro" expended to the username.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Stupid me didn't see it in the documentation.